# Laravel how to get count specific data by school id?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have laravel queries below

```
$school = DB::table('sekolah')->get();

$morning_session =  DB::table('sekolah')->join('pelajar', 'sekolah.sekolah_id', '=', 'pelajar.sekolah_id') ->where('pelajar.pelajar_sesi', 'like', 'Morning')->groupBy('pelajar.sekolah_id')->count();

$afternoon_session =  DB::table('sekolah')->join('pelajar', 'sekolah.sekolah_id', '=', 'pelajar.sekolah_id')->where('pelajar.pelajar_sesi', 'like', 'Afternoon')->groupBy('pelajar.sekolah_id')->count();
```

my blade look like this

```
@foreach($school as $d) 
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <i class="fa fa-mortar-board" style="font-size:80px;display:block;text-align:center"></i>
         <h4>{{$d->sekolah_nama}}</h4>
         <!-- morning session -->
         <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Morning: {{$morning_session}} people
         <!-- afternoon session -->
         <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Afternoon: {{$afternoon_session}}
        </div>
@endforeach
```

I want make a count for morning and afternoon session foreach school id. but the result show only pelajar.sekolah_id = 1  [school website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39sao.png) . You can refer my table below at [student table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLdD9.png)

Comment: why you have this part `->groupBy('pelajar.sekolah_id')` ?

Comment: @AnarBayramov because i want result of count of morning and afternoon session for each school.but i'm not sure how to write a code correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can see, you might be able to use something like this:

```
$morning_session =  DB::table('pelajar')
    ->select('sekolah_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->where('pelajar_sesi', 'like', 'Morning')
    ->groupBy('sekolah_id')
    ->pluck('total','sekolah_id')->all();

$afternoon_session =  DB::table('pelajar')
    ->select('sekolah_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
    ->where('pelajar_sesi', 'like', 'Afternoon')
    ->groupBy('sekolah_id')
    ->pluck('total','sekolah_id')->all();
```

Then in your view something like:

```
Morning: {{!empty($morning_session[$d->sekolah_id]) ? $morning_session[$d->sekolah_id] : '0'}} people
```

I hope I am understanding your question and this helps.

Comment: So you will need a condition in your view, I have updated my answer

Comment: No problem. Feel free to up vote the answer if it helped.